# Comment mieux formuler « on est pris avec des professeurs qui ne font que projeter des diapositives et réciter leur contenu »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dans notre département, nous sommes pris avec des professeurs incompétents qui n’ont rien de mieux à faire que de projeter des diapositives et de lire textuellement et machinalement le contenu de ces dernières, de vrais incompétents dans leur discipline. Ce qu’ils font devant la classe, je le fais chez moi, je n’apprends absolument rien d’eux.

Comment: Il faudrait être plus explicite sur le sens à donner à « prendre avec » ici. *Prendre* peut pendre tellement de sens différents...  nous sommes saisis/attrapés avec eux ? *surpris* (mais ça ne collerait pas avec *des professeurs*) ... Peut-être ne veux-tu pas dire *prendre* mais *prendre en charge*, ce qui pourrait avoir un sens avec la suite  : *nous sommes pris en charge par des professeurs*, mais ça n'a pas du tout le même sens que *pris par des professeurs*.

Comment: En fait je voulais donner une connotation négative de « prendre en charge » en lui prêtant un sens voisin de « être pogné avec des professeurs incapables, « être obligé de prendre des cours avec des professeurs incompétents ». « Être pogné avec qqun comme dans être pogné avec psychopathe » est d’usage courant à oral dans mon sociolecte. —> Être pris-onnier de ces professeurs.

Comment: https://www.wanderingfrench.com/qc-006/

Comment: Alors peut-être que *par* conviendrait mieux que *avec* ? Du moins pour rendre le sens. En France *pogner* n'est pas utilisé et je pense pas souvent compris...  je ne vois rien d'aussi imagé que pogner !

Comment: Dans la mesure du possible, je souhaiterais qu’on me présente des refontes qui n’utilisent pas le verbe « prendre » ou « pogner » ni « n’avoir rien de mieux à faire que », tournure que je trouve inélégante.

Comment: On est **aux prises avec des professeurs** etc.

Comment: Pour adresser plutôt le contenu de la phrase: d'abord, beaucoup d'étudiants manquent d'envie ou simplement de la discipline pour apprendre eux-mêmes d'un texte (même s'ils en sont parfaitement capables), donc ces professeurs assurent le minimum. En outre, la rôle d'un prof n'est pas forcément communiquer l'information (qui peuvent être trouvée ailleurs), mais l'expliquer et répondre aux questions, en façon pédagogique (la manière adaptée aux capacités d'étudiants). Du coup, ils sont souvent obligés par leur supérieurs de faire exactement ça : lire le contenu de diapositifs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour éviter *être pris/se ramasser avec* on pourrait dire simplement :

> *Dans notre département, on se retrouve avec des professeurs...*

Answer (score 1):

-- « Pris avec » est visiblement « pris par » ( (TLFi) enserré, enveloppé, bloqué).

-- Qu'ils « n'ont rien de mieux » n'est pas nécessairement le cas—on sait très bien qu'il est permis à un enseignant beaucoup d'initiative personnelle dans la manière de faire un cours—, et il ne serait question que de choix personnel.

-- « Leur contenu » est bien vague ; à eux ? qu'il leur est dévolu de débiter dans les salles de classe en vertu des directives académiques ? « Contenu » ne signifie pas encore « texte » ou ce qui se trouve sur un écran d'ordinateur en français ; c'est un américanisme.

> [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contenu)
> [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/contenu/18582)

-- Il ne faudrait pas répéter « incompétent », mais un terme apparenté n'enlève rien au style ; par exemple, « inqualifié » est un bon choix.

- Dans notre département, nous sommes pris *par* des professeurs incompétents qui ne trouvent rien de mieux à faire que de projeter des diapositives et lire textuellement et machinalement leurs textes d'explication, des individus qui dans leur discipline même ne sont pas qualifiés. Ce qu’ils font devant une classe, je peux le faire chez moi, ce qui montre que  je n’apprends d’eux absolument rien.

Comment: Ce qui est projeté en diapositives, c’est le contenu intégral du livre. Dans d’autres cours ce sont des versions numériques des livres de référence qui sont projetées (dit-on projeté en numérique??) sur un écran blanc devant la classe. Lors du cours magistral, les professeurs concernés ne font que lire mot pour mot et machinalement ce qui est écrit, sans même prendre la peine de commenter ne serait-ce que les passages plus obscurs ou de donner quelques explications par-ci et par-là. Il en va de même pour les exercices et les problèmes: les solutions sont carrément domper dans leur entièreté.

Comment: Peut-on qualifier d’enseignement cette manière de faire un cours?

Comment: Correction premier commentaire: dompées et non domper.

Comment: @Thérèse 1/ Toute question sur la valeur d'une méthode d'enseignement, surtout une méthode qui ne concerne pas particulièrement l'enseignement du français, ne peut pas faire l'objet d'une discussion. 2/ Je ne vois pas bien comment serait utilisé « contenu » ; a) Ensemble de choses ? Mais on ne lit pas des illustrations ; quelles sont ces choses ? Des phrases ?  b) Esemble d'idées ? Mais on ne lit pas les idées. 3/ Je crois qu'il s'agit de l'anglais « to dump » ; on ne l'utilise en français métropolitain que dans le commerce (dumping) ou les travaux de terrassement. Néanmoins, je comprend.

Comment: Je suis entièrement d’accord avec vous, entre autres « contenu » n’est pas adapté ici.

Answer (score 0):

> Aux prises avec, en lutte contre quelqu'un, confronté à quelque chose.

- On est aux prises avec des professeurs qui [etc.]
- On est confronté à des professeurs qui [etc.]

[aux prises_Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/prise/63987#:%7E:text=Aux%20prises%20avec%2C,un%2C%20confront%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%20quelque%20chose.)

Comment: Je dois t’avouer ne pas comprendre pourquoi ces formulations triviales ne se sont pas présentées à mon esprit, principalement la première; je conjecture que c’est imputable à une atrophie prématurée de ma gaine de myéline, structure qui joue le  rôle d’isolant, à l’instar de la gaine protectrice des fils électriques,  dans la conduction des informations entre neurones dans le cerveau.

Comment: *Je dois vous avouer…, toutes mes excuses.

Comment: Cette situation d'avoir à supporter des professeurs dont on ne trouve pas la méthode très bonne ne va pas jusqu'au point de l'antagonisme ouvert et constant, ou rarement (être aux prises (TLFi) :  Au fig. Être en lutte contre, avoir à affronter (quelque chose).). Cette expression est trop forte.

Comment: @Thérèse Alors là, vous me faites rire. :)

Comment: @LPH Il me semble que le sens où cela veut dire "confronter à" marche très bien. J'ai reçu deux votes positifs dans les commentaires.

Comment: @Lambie « Confronter » est suffisamment proche de « pris par », je n'ai rien dis à ce sujet. By the way, the downvote is not mine.

Comment: @LPH "aux prises"  n'est pas si fort étant donné le vouloir dire Thérèse. C'est confronter **à**x.

Comment: @Lambie 1/ Non pas « confronter » mais « affronter » : ((TLFi) : a) (Être, mettre) aux prises. Se battre, faire se battre (comme si on exécutait une suite de prises). Les mains s'abattirent sur les figures, un pugilat général mit aux prises les forcenés (Vogüé, Morts,1899, p. 373).
− Au fig. Être en lutte contre, avoir à affronter (quelque chose). ) 2/  « étant donné le vouloir dire de Thérèse » ; ce vouloir-dire est rendu  précis dans ses commentaires : « être obligé de prendre des cours avec des professeurs […] ». « Être « _pogné_ » avec qqun  -> Être pris-onnier de ces professeurs » (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie C'est justement dans cette explication que l'on voit que c'est son terme (« pris avec » sauf que « avec » n'est pas correct et doit être remplacé par « par ») qui correspond à son vouloir-dire, c'est à dire « bloqué, accaparé, immobilisé, …) ; on trouve que l'usage littéral « [de bateaux et autres choses **pris par** les glaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pris%20par%20les%20glaces%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » fournit une excellente analogie. (2/2)

Comment: @Lambie Un cas de sens figuré bien connu : « _pris par ses affaires_ ».

Comment: @LPH Ô ciel  Je suis confrontée à une machine perpétuelle de contradictiions fatigantes.